# linux desktop executable python script

Tags: python, linux, desktop

I tried to make a simple python script executable, and therefore googled what to do.
Here's what I got so far

.desktop

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Name=helloworld
Comment=
Exec=./test.py
Icon=
Path=/home/xxx/Desktop
Terminal=true
StartupNotify=false
```

python file

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
print('hello world')
```

On the terminal I did chmod +x test.py and now it is possible to execute it in the terminal via ./test.py

If I double click on the desktop icon I can see the terminal open for a really short time but then it closed really quick.

What am I doing wrong?

I expected the desktop icon to open the terminal and then shows my python script.

thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The terminal window will close when the script is finished. You can put

```
input()     # Python 3
raw_input() # Python 2
```

at the bottom of the script to close on enter press.

Comment: need 12 more minutes to acceppt this ;)

Comment: is this the common way to do so?

Comment: I think so. Normally people don't run instantaneous scripts from a shortcut, though. Programs like [Ranger](http://ranger.nongnu.org/screenshots.html) already stay alive for long periods of time and other programs that don't are almost never run like this. // Some terminals support waiting on exit, but then you're locking yourself into a few terminals. This way you can use all of 'em.

Comment: the terminal is blank

Answer (score 0):

@Veedrac that is not the correct way.
The correct way is to use `time.sleep()` which works both in Python 3.x and 2.x.
Use the following code to do that.

```
import time # Should be the first statement.
# Some code is below. This code is useless. 
print()
def blah():
    print('bhahfdjfdk')
blah()
# When the program ends, use the code below to keep it running for some more time.
time.sleep(2) # In the parentheses you can replace 2 with the number of seconds you want to put the program on hold. This will help you and is the official Python way.
```